# An infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I know the infinite sum of the sequence $F_{n}$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
S_{1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} F_{n}
\end{equation}
where $S_{1}$ is a real finite number and it's known. What can one say about the following sum
\begin{equation}
S_{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{F_{n}}{2^{n}}
\end{equation}
Is it possible to evaluate $S_{2}$ in terms of $S_{1}$?

Comment: Certainly not. $2+4 = 4+2$, but $2+4/2\ne 4+2/2$.

Comment: As David said, no it is not enough for *evaluation*, but there are things you can say about $S_2$. E.g. $S_2$ also clearly exists, for starters.

Comment: I see David. Thank you both.